# Gitlab Runner on separate server

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ce

I want to install GitLab Runner on a separate server, but when I try to connect to GitLab, I received:

```
Running in system-mode.                            

Please enter the gitlab-ci coordinator URL (e.g. https://gitlab.com/):
<URL>
Please enter the gitlab-ci token for this runner:
<TOKEN>       
Please enter the gitlab-ci description for this runner:
[<url>]: <description>
Please enter the gitlab-ci tags for this runner (comma separated):

Whether to lock Runner to current project [true/false]:
[false]: 
ERROR: Registering runner... failed                 runner=<runner-token> status=couldn't execute POST against <url>/api/v4/runners: Post <url>/api/v4/runners: dial tcp 172.17.0.2:80: getsockopt: connection refused
ERROR: Checking GitLab compatibility... not-compatible  reason=GitLab Runner >= 9.0 can be used ONLY with GitLab CE/EE >= 9.0 result=-1 runner=<runner-token> statusText=couldn't execute POST against <url>/api/v4/runners/verify: Post <url>/api/v4/runners/verify: dial tcp 172.17.0.2:80: getsockopt: connection refused
PANIC: Failed to register this runner. Perhaps you are having network problems
```

If I create POST request from POSTMAN I can create runner, but when I try from gitlab-ci I can't. Do you know what is wrong ? Our Gitlab is on another server, and I want to separate Gitlab and Gitlab-ci. I want Gitlab-CI to be on a separate server, not in the same server where is Gitlab. How to do that, do you know ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible causes for your issue:

1. **Version mismatch**: Probably your runner is not compatible  with your GitLab version as described in the message: `ERROR: Checking GitLab compatibility... not-compatible  reason=GitLab Runner >= 9.0 can be used ONLY with GitLab CE/EE >= 9.0 result=-1`. Check your GitLab instance version and make sure your runner version is compatible with it.

   > Runners version 9.0 and above utilize the new v4 API, requiring a minimum of GitLab 9.0.
2. **Network problem**: Your Gitlab Runner is not able to reach the GitLab server due to some network limitation or due to some block. When this happen, the same error message from above is shown. Try to curl *`<url>/api/v4/runners/verify`* from the GitLab Runner server to know if this is the problem.

Comment: Hi @alejdg Thanks for your reply. 
> About 1 I use latest versions for GitLab and GitLab CI.
> About 2 I tried to run this command: `curl -X POST --form "token=xxxxx" <url>/api/v4/runners/verify`. And received {"message":"403 Forbidden"}. Do you have any idea what's wrong ? By the way our url has https and Basic Auth. And my url is `https://user:pass@url/api/v4/runners/verify`

Comment: Try looking at the logs in your Gitlab server in order to find more info about it. You could start with nginx log: `gitlab-ctl tail nginx` and secure log: `tail -f /var/log/secure`.  Monitor the log while trying to register.

Comment: @Krasimir post any new info here so we can find the solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yep I fixed my problem. What was the problem: I've created docker-compose.yml file and it looks like this:

```
web:
  image: 'gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest'
  restart: always
  hostname: domain
  container_name: gitlab-runner
  volumes:
    - '/storage/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner'
    - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

but, when I tried to connect gitlab and gitlab ci, I saw that in this line:
`Please enter the gitlab-ci description for this runner: [<url>]:
 <description>`
I received `[<url>]`, but I have to receive random token vs url. Then I decide to remove `hostname: domain` and started the process again. Then all works well. So my new `docker-compose.yml` file looks like:

```
web:
  image: 'gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest'
  restart: always
  container_name: gitlab-runner
  volumes:
    - '/storage/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner'
    - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

And now all works well.

Comment: Nice to know that you have found a solution.